# how to create folder in Wix?

Tags: wix

I use this code:

```
'<'Directory Id="x" Name="ext">
  <'Component Id="y" Guid="4480e442-42d9-41a8-a091-9bdbf5aa47df">
    <'CreateFolder Directory="ext" />
  <'/Component>
'<'/Directory>
```

But it failed with the following error:

> : error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'Directory:ext' in section 'Product:*'.

what could be the problem? BTW: I have difficulties pasting the XML code in this form.

Answer (score 1):

This should be Directory Id, not the name:

```
<CreateFolder Directory="x" />
```

Or just

```
<CreateFolder/>
```

to create the containing directory if you are not going to write any file there.